How can I use shapekeys to morph from a plane/grid into a complex object?
If I have 2 objects, one is a plane/grid and the other is a cube with an archway. Is there a way to morph from the plane into the archway using shapekeys?
The main reason I ask this is because I want to preserve the UV map of the grid, but displace its vector data into the arch, essentially copying the overhang

From Discord: user wants to create VDM brushes as in this tutorial

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

@StefLAncien how do I that? Sorry I'm kind of new to this site

Upload your file on this web site, filling the form (particularly the URL of your question, i.e. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/324448). After uploading, it will display some htlm commands. Just copy it. Open your question here with the "Edit" button and paste the html command at the end of your question.
